# Webmatrix/Razor C#: How should I set initial value for db.query(SQL) based on user input and display query variable?

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

I am trying to create an UI for internal employees. I would like to perform select statements based on user input (id, value) and display the query, so the researcher can check the query as well as sample output, before using the info for further processes.

This is what I have in the code block:

```
var db = Database.Open("database");
...
switch (input)
{
case "1":
        Query2 = "select ... from table where value = @1;
        break;
case "2":
        Query2 = "select ... from table where value = @1;
        break; 
}

var Query1 = "select ... from table where id = @0";
var Query2 = "select ... from table where value = @1";
```

In the html page, I call the var by

```
@Query1
@Query2
```

Question 1:
Assume the user chooses 1 for id and 100 for value
I see on the webpage:

```
"select ... from table where id = @0" and "select ... from table where value = @1"
```

instead of

```
"select ... from table where id = 1" and "select ... from table where value = 100"
```

What should I have done differently?

Question 2:
db.query(SQL) does not like empty string or null value. What can I set SQL to before user chooses any input? I would not like to show anything on the webpage without selection - not even the default query.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Your are building a string `var Query1 = "Select ... from table where id = @0"`. @0 is not a value, you should replace it with value or use String.Format(string format, params object[] args) ?